# View Android phone's call log from PC

Tags: call-history

My Android phone's screen suddenly stopped working - gone totally blank. I am getting lots of incoming calls, but am unable to view who is calling or pick the call. Also just before it stopped working, I had put it in Silent Mode with Vibration. So I have to listen to vibration to know that someone is calling, and there is no way I can turn Sound On now.

I want to access my phone's call log from PC by connecting using USB cable. There are many softwares, but they require to be installed on phone also. While I can install the software on the phone using MobileGo, but I may not be able to read the port no. on which the software is listening.

Is there any software which I can install just on my PC (like MobileGo) and directly access phone's Call Log? MobileGo has many useful features but this one is missing.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you rooted? Which phone? What version of Android?

Comment: I am not rooted. Phone Model is Motorola Fore XT 535. Android 2.3.x I guess (can't verify now)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also install the software directly from the Android market. But you won't be able to start it easily. You can use ADB to start the app as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567904/how-to-start-an-application-using-android-adb-tools)

I recommend [MyPhoneExplorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fjsoft.myphoneexplorer.client). You'll also need to install the desktop program and then start the app on your phone as mentioned in the link above.

Be mindful of any optional toolbar that might ask to be installed on your desktop though.

UPDATE: I didn't need to start the app on my phone, merely connecting the cable was enough. Galaxy S2 on Gingerbread 2.3.3 (rooted, but that shouldn't be a factor).

Comment: Thanks. I was able to install MyPhoneExplorer client on the phone. I have gone through the adb command to start an acitivity on the phone, but it requires package name and activity name. Using MobileGo, I was able to find package name, but how do I find which activity? I gave this command in adb shell:  am start -n com.fjsoft.myphoneexplorer.client.apk, but it says Bad Component Name .. I guess because I have not specified Activity Name.

Comment: I was able to run the PhoneExplorer client on my phone using this command in adb shell: am start -n com.fjsoft.myphoneexplorer.client/com.fjsoft.myphoneexplorer.client.MainActivity. I came to know about the activity following the steps in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5728903/reading-activity-names-from-apk-file-in-android. Finally I installed MyPhoneExplorer on my PC and was able to view the Call Log! Thanks a ton! Sparx, you have been of great help.

Comment: One last question, I had mentioned that I had put my phone in Silent Mode just before the screen problem happened. How can I now turn Sound On on the phone using my PC?

Comment: If your screen alone isn't working, I expect your volume keys must be - just press the side volume keys while your phone is on. When connected via the cable the phone will be on so one can probably increase the ringer volume then.

Comment: If you were rooted, I'd suggest androidscreencast - https://code.google.com/p/androidscreencast/ | it allows a user to control the android device using the PC/mouse but it needs root.

Comment: >> adb shell input keyevent 20 << will simulate pressing vol up. More details here - http://thecodeartist.blogspot.in/2011/03/simulating-keyevents-on-android-device.html

Comment: Complete your user profile - that will give you some points instantly. Also, look for a tick mark next to the answer. Clicking that means you accept that as the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can install any software from the [Market / Google Play](https://play.google.com/store). Log in using the account used on your device and you can install any software.
The app will be automatically downloaded (pushed) and installed onto your device when the device is online.

Via USB I think you can only access such information in case the *USB debugging* is enabled on your device. With it enabled you have access to the file system and further options via Android Debug Bridge (ADB).

But as your device is defect it would be much simpler to just buy or lend a cheap device and use it instead...

Answer (score 0):

Use Android Device Manager. Install the device both in your android phone and your machine (pc) . Then sign in using your details and you can view all the details in your PC. That's like basically remotely controlling your device. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: If you're referring to Google's "Android Device Manager" that comes up at the top of [this search](https://www.google.com/search?q=android+device+manager) then you're mistaken as to what it does.  You can find/erase/lock your device but there is nothing like *`basically remotely controlling your device`*.  If you're referring to another app, can you provide the link and more information?  (also, what do you mean *`Install the device...`*?)